# Filling shape with horizontal lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a triangle with another shape inside, something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw, ultra thick] (0,0) -- (5,5) -- (10,0)--cycle;
\path[draw, ultra thick] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,3.5) -- (8,2) -- (8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: this is how it looks like]

now I want to fill the shape inside the triangle with horizontal lines and a label in the middle.
so the first question is how can I do the lines? and the second is how can I make the label cut the lines, I mean something like this: -----A----- just not dashed...

and a bonus question :) is there a better way to draw this triangle assuming I know the length of all 3 sides? (the length of the bottom one is the sqrt72...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A basic approach to fill the triangle with horizontal lines without using libraries is to use `\foreach` to draw the lines inside the triangle using the triangle as `clip`ping path. For the label, just use a normal node filled white.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw, ultra thick] (0,0) --node[above,pos=.35,sloped]{4 cm}node[above,pos=.85,sloped]{2 cm} (5,5) -- (10,0)--cycle;
\path[draw, ultra thick] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,3.5) -- (8,2) -- (8,0);
\path[clip] (0,0) -- (5,5) -- (10,0)--cycle;
\foreach \y in{0,.2,...,5}
  \draw (0,\y) -- (10,\y);
\node at (5,2)[fill=white]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use the `patterns` library as suggested by @percusse like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw, ultra thick,pattern=horizontal lines] (0,0) --node[above,pos=.35,sloped]{4 cm}node[above,pos=.85,sloped]{2 cm} (5,5) -- (10,0)--cycle;
\path[draw, ultra thick] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,3.5) -- (8,2) -- (8,0);
\node at (5,2)[fill=white]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

with a slightly different output (which you can still tweak):

[image]

**Edit:**

I think I initially misunderstood the question, it seems the shape inside the triangle is to be filled instead. Any way, here is the modified code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw, ultra thick] (0,0) --node[above,pos=.35,sloped]{4 cm}node[above,pos=.85,sloped]{2 cm} (5,5) -- (10,0)--cycle;
\path[draw, ultra thick,pattern=horizontal lines] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,3.5) -- (8,2) -- (8,0);
\node at (5.75,1.5) [fill=white]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just using patterns instead of clipping and drawing lines?

Comment: Yes, that is possible of course as I said, I just tend to over-use basics. I'll add that, thank you.